# Why ping don't response for long time even -W is specified?

Tags: linux, networking, ping, icmp, tcp-ip

I'm just confused with ping. As per my understanding, when I ping some IP address, it sends an ICMP message to the destination, and if there is no response, it get either "request timeout" or "destination unreachable". But when I use ping to detect connectivity of a remote server, e.g. to detect whether the server rebooted, something weird happened: it takes maybe 40 seconds or more to receive "destination unreachable". Even I set "-W 1", it still takes such a long time.

Despite I resolved the issue with "-O" option, which tells me "no answer yet for icmp_seq=x", but I still cannot understand why it takes such a long time to get "destination unreachable", even with "-W 1"?

Comment: You don't *have* to get  t get a response at all. Any node on the way could silently drop your echo request, and that'd be it.

Comment: Experience on Solaris: DNS resolution was taking 90 seconds to time out (even on a LAN), and ping does not monitor that delay. Ping only starts the -W timer for ping packets. You can `timeout 5 ping -W 1`, but if you go too short or do multiple packets, you will get a misleading result.